# buildbot and cmake cannot create vs2010 generator

Tags: windows, cmake, buildbot

i mount a continious integration plateform with buildbot, the project use cmake for generate a visual studio 2010 solution.

for test purpose i use my windows dev vm for the buildslave, cmake die with a strange error

> CMake Error: Could not create named
>   generator "Visual Studio 10"

but if i do the cmake manualy, it's work fine

> cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" source

the config of this buildslave:

```
factoryWin = BuildFactory()
factoryWin.addStep(SVN(svnurl=repo_url, mode='copy', username=svn_user, password=svn_passwd))
factoryWin.addStep(ShellCommand(command=['cmake', '-G"Visual Studio 10"', 'source']))


c['builders'].append(
BuilderConfig(name="runtests-win",
slavenames=["win-slave"],
factory=factoryWin)
```

are you have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my situation I had to resolve this problem with the use of an environment variable.  The command then becomes:

```
factoryWin.addStep(ShellCommand(command=['cmake', '-G%CMAKEGENERATOR%', 'source'],
     env={"CMAKEGENERATOR": "\"Visual Studio 10\""}))
```

This I think stops the twisted runprocess from manipulating the string.  In my case I also wanted to set up the Visual Studio command environment so my command is:

```
factoryWin.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\bin\\vcvars32.bat", "x86",
     "&&", "cmake", "-G%CMAKEGENERATOR%", "..\\src"],
     env={"CMAKEGENERATOR": "\"Visual Studio 10\""}))
```

Obviously I have my relative path between my build directory and src directory different but  the outcome is the same, namely a Visual Studio solution generated by cmake.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you're not using cygwin's cmake by accident (in case you happened to install cygwin)

This one cannot build VS.

Comment: I do not think, when i had a space before '-G...' it's work, so the problem is solved, but it's strange

Comment: Thanks - building something unrelated I ran into this same problem with cmake being part of cygwin

Answer (score 2):

In your case I THINK that your issue is that the array should read

```
['cmake', '-G', "Visual Studio 10", 'source']
```

rather than

```
['cmake', '-G"Visual Studio 10"', 'source']
```

The quotes in the error you are seeing are part of the string and are not a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the environment variable answer should necessarily be considered the 'best' answer. It's a simple issue of not using the correct format for the string.

This syntax can also be used.
`['cmake', '-GVisual Studio 10', 'source']`

I wrote a CMakeCommand class that inherits from ShellCommand, that allows keywords to specify the generator and the sourceDir. It's a stripped version that only specifies the generator and source dir, but it can be extended to include CMake flags, etc.

```
class CMakeCommand(ShellCommand):

    name = "generate"
    description = "generating"
    descriptionDone = "generate"

    generator="Visual Studio 10"
    sourceDir = "../"

    def __init__( self, 
                  generator="Visual Studio 10",
                  sourceDir = "../",
                  **kwargs ):

        self.generator = generator
        self.sourceDir = sourceDir

        # always upcall!
        ShellCommand.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        self.addFactoryArguments(
            generator = generator,
            sourceDir = sourceDir,
        )
    def start(self):

        tempCommand = ["cmake", "-G", self.generator ]
        # Add any flags here
        # tempCommand.append( "-DBUILDNAME=buildbot" )
        tempCommand.append( self.sourceDir )
        self.setCommand( tempCommand )

        return ShellCommand.start( self )
```

Example step usage:

```
factoryWin.addStep(
    CMakeCommand(
        generator="Visual Studio 10",
        sourceDir = "../SVN_CO", # Top level CMakeLists.txt
        workdir="vc100", # where the build tree will be placed. Automatically created.
    )
)
```